# How to pass an array of float3 values from CPU to GPU in Metal?

Tags: ios, metal, metal-performance-shaders

I have a requirement to pass the color values to the shader as an array. Right now I'm passing it as a structure RGBColors and receiving it as a structure and it is working fine.

But I want to receive it as float3 value in the shader. But as soon as I change it to float3 it is acting weird and it starts to flicker, it is not giving me proper color.

Here is the code I used to set the fragment buffer,

```
func setFragmentBuffer(_ values: [Float], at index: Int) {
     let bufferValues = values
     let datasize = 16 * values.count / 3

     let colorBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: bufferValues, length: datasize, options: [])
     renderEncoder.setFragmentBuffer(colorBuffer, offset: 0, at: index)
}
```

Here is the structure for the RGBColors

```
struct RGBColors {
    var r: Float
    var g: Float
    var b: Float

    func floatBuffers() -> [Float] {
        return [r,g,b]
    }
}
```

From this structure I will create an array of `Float` values and set it to fragment buffer.

The code `let datasize = 16 * values.count / 3` I gave the value 16 because the although float data type in C++ is 4 bytes float3 in simd is 16 bytes.

And in the shader I'm implementing the method

```
fragment float4
singleShader(RasterizerData in [[stage_in]],
                   texture2d<half> sourceTexture [[ texture(0) ]],
                   const device float3 &rgbColor [[ buffer(1) ]]
{
    constexpr sampler textureSampler (mag_filter::linear,
                                      min_filter::linear);

    // Sample the texture and return the color to colorSample
    const half4 colorSample = sourceTexture.sample (textureSampler, in.textureCoordinate);

    float4 outputColor;


    float red = colorSample.r * rgbColor.r;
    float green = colorSample.g * rgbColor.g;
    float blue =  colorSample.b * rgbColor.b;

    outputColor = float4(red, green,blue, colorSample.a);
    outputColor = float4((outputColor.rgb * param1 + param2) / 4, colorSample.a);
    return outputColor;
}
```

Finally I'm not getting the right output color.

How to match `float3 simd` data type to the `swift Float` data type. Can someone suggest me?

**Edit:**

I found a solution about how to create a MTLBuffer from float3 and here is the code:

```
func setFragmentBuffer(_ values: [float3], at index: Int) {
    var valueBuffer = values

    let bufferCreated = device.makeBuffer(length: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: valueBuffer[0]) * 2 * valueBuffer.count , options: [])
    let bufferPointer = bufferCreated.contents()

    memcpy(bufferPointer, &valueBuffer, 16 * valueBuffer.count)
    renderEncoder.setFragmentBuffer(bufferCreated, offset: 0, at: index)
}
```

This code works perfectly fine. But still in the code `let bufferCreated = device.makeBuffer(length: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: valueBuffer[0]) * 2 * valueBuffer.count , options: [])` you can see that a the length should be multiplied by a factor of **2** to make the code work.

Why there should a multiplier to make it work? Im not understanding this. Could someone suggest me?

Comment: You acknowledge that `float3` is 16 bytes in size (and alignment), but you don't seem to recognize that that means there's padding between the individual floats for one element and those of the next. Where do you propose that padding would come from in your code? If you insist on using an array of floats, you're going to have to lay them out with the padding yourself in the buffer. Are you aware that you can import simd in Swift and just use the `float3` type there? Much simpler and easier to do that instead of using your ad hoc `RGBColors` struct.

Comment: Yeah I know you can use simd for float3 data type. But how do you convert float3 into a MTLBuffer from device to set the fragmentBuffer through an encoder. Because the `device.makebuffer(:)` method requires a UnsafeRawPointer where float3 cannot be converted into, because it is not conformed to Strideable and Hashable. Could you suggest me?

Comment: @KenThomases I updated the code and I'm able to use float3 instead of Float and create the MTLBuffers out of it. But still I have some query regarding the multiplier. Could you tell me why is that required?

Comment: I'm not sure. What result does `MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: valueBuffer[0])` produce? In any case, you should be using `stride`, not `size`. In what way does the code not work if you don't multiply by 2?

Comment: @KenThomases, I was doing a mistake in shader. Instead of using float3 I was still using the struct in the shader. And also the stride method seems to work out for me instead of size. And I don't need to multiply it with 2. Thanks for the responses.